# ng2-redux initial state for list of objects

Tags: angular, redux

I am a beginner to ng2-flux . I have implemented a employee store and it needs a call to employee db to get the INITIAL_STATE for the same . How or where do I place it .

**employee.types.ts**  --

```
import { TypedRecord, makeTypedFactory } from 'typed-immutable-record';

import { IEmployee } from "../../common/models";

export interface IEmployeeState extends Array<IEmployee> { }

// const INITIAL_STATE =
```

**employee.reducer.ts** --

```
import { IEmployee } from "../common/models/index";

export const EmployeeReducer = (state: Array<IEmployee> = null, action: any) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case action.ADD_EMPLOYEE:
            return [...state, action.payload]
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I need to call an initial API to initialize the state . Since it is not an Angular2 service and it is just an reducer . How do I do this .